Is there a better way to generate my dataframe?
I have a set of data that I need to perform some transformations on. The raw form of the data is as follows (actual dataset will have many more columns, reduced set here for simplicity):



lVoterUniqueID
sElectionAbbr1
sElectionAbbr2
sElectionAbbr3
sElectionAbbr4
sElectionAbbr5




371527
2024PR
2022Gen
2022PR
2020GEN
2020PR


1843949
2024PR
null
null
null
null


2813398
2024PR
2022Gen
null
2020GEN
2020PR



The output I'm looking for is:

lVoterUniqueID relabeled as ID

Each sElectionAbbr[X] column relabeled to Election_Code





ID
Election_Code




371527
2024PR


1843949
2024PR



I can accomplish this via sql:
select distinct 
lVoterUniqueID,
sElectionAbbr1 as Election_Code
from data_set
where sElectionAbbr1 != ''
union 
select distinct 
lVoterUniqueID,
sElectionAbbr2
from data_set
where sElectionAbbr2 != ''
union ...

However, I wanted to do this within Python and I've accomplished that goal, but it feels like the process is a bit heavy handed and I'm wondering if there is a more efficient way to do this.
Working Python below:
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv([path to data file])
#find number of election columns. 
selected_columns = [column for column in df.columns if column.startswith("sElection")]
#add voter id column
selected_columns.insert(0,'lVoterUniqueID')

#create dataframe schema
rcdp_voters_prod = pd.DataFrame(columns=['ID','Election_Code'])

def access_elements(list_var, list_index):
    # Use list comprehension to create a new list containing elements from 'list_var' at the specified indices in 'list_index'
    result = [list_var[i] for i in list_index]
    return result

#indices of list values that hold the election column
python_indices  = [index for (index, item) in enumerate(selected_columns) if item != "lVoterUniqueID"]

union_dict = {}

#Create dictionary of lists containing unique voterid and each election abbreviation column
# ['lVoterUniqueID', 'sElectionAbbr1']
# ['lVoterUniqueID', 'sElectionAbbr2']
# ['lVoterUniqueID', 'sElectionAbbr3']
# ['lVoterUniqueID', 'sElectionAbbr4']
# ['lVoterUniqueID', 'sElectionAbbr5']
for index in python_indices:
    union_dict.update({index:access_elements(selected_columns,[0,index])})

dataframe_list = []

#create list of dataframes containing only distinct columns from column list
#rename columns for concating
for key in union_dict:
    loop_df = df.filter(items=union_dict[key]).drop_duplicates()
    loop_df.rename(columns={'lVoterUniqueID':'ID',union_dict[key][1]:'Election_Code'}, inplace= True)
    dataframe_list.append(loop_df)


final_frame_form = pd.concat(dataframe_list)
#drop rows where election code is null
final_frame_form=final_frame_form[final_frame_form['Election_Code'].notnull()]


I think pd.melt() is what you're looking for.
import pandas as pd

# Test data
data = [
    {"lVoterUniqueID": 1, "sElectionAbbr1": "111 street", "sElectionAbbr2": "222 street"},
    {"lVoterUniqueID": 2, "sElectionAbbr1": "333 street", "sElectionAbbr2": "444 street"},
]
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
df.rename({"lVoterUniqueID": "id"}, axis=1, inplace=True)

# Get list of columns to melt
election_cols = [x for x in df.columns.to_list() if "sElectionAbbr" in x]

# Melt the data
df = pd.melt(df, id_vars=["id"], value_vars=election_cols, var_name="election", value_name="election_code")

# Cleanup
df.drop("election", axis=1, inplace=True)
print(df)

